# ASP.VB Net 3.5 Framework: what can I use to replace deprecated Stringtype.FromObject

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, frameworks

I'm coverted legacy code of a .NET Framework 1.0 web application.  It contains the method StringType.FromObject ..... is there a replacement for this?  Thanks in advance!

```
labelAlerts.Text = StringType.FromObject(GetArticles("DispAreaAlerts"));
```

Comment: LOL "This class supports the Visual Basic compiler and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

Comment: Can you help me understand what it does as I'm trying to get this code converted to Framework 3.5?  Any suggestions on how to code the above statement? Thanks!

Comment: oh, I see ... I'm using Reflector and it is throwing in some compliler code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetArticles("DispAreaAlerts").ToString()
```